# Mysql multiple inserts support how many extended values?

Tags: mysql

We all know that it's better to use multiple inserts in ONE query than to run MULTIPLE queries. But, I don't know upto how many these multiple extended values does Mysql support? I searched over net but didn't find the correct answer. I'm just curious to know this.

Example,

`INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES(1, 'John Doe'), (2, 'Peter England'), ....`

I remember when I was using some MVC framework where it was trying to fire hundreds/thousands of inserts in one query, I used to get some sort of error message like `Mysql server has gone away`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit for multiple inserts, like the one you are talking about would be bound by the packet limit.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

This will affect all query types, and not just insert.

To add a little more context, the error you spoke of [MySQL server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) would be a result of exceeding the packet limit. A quote from the page:

> You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that
>   is incorrect or too large. If mysqld receives a packet that is **too
>   large** or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with
>   the client and closes the connection. If you need big queries (for
>   example, if you are working with big BLOB columns), you can increase
>   the query limit by setting the server's **max_allowed_packet** variable,
>   which has a **default value of 1MB**. You may also need to increase the
>   maximum packet size on the client end. More information on setting the
>   packet size is given in Section C.5.2.10, “Packet too large”.

Answer (score 1):

Your query's ultimate length limit is set by the [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) setting - if you exceed that, the query gets truncated and almost certainly becomes invalid.

While doing a multi-value insert is more efficient, don't go overboard and try to do thousands of value sets. Try splitting it up so you're only doing a few hundred at most, and definitely make sure that the query string's length doesn't go near max_allowed_packet.